# Let $V$ be an $n$-dimensional vector space, and let $T: V \rightarrow V$ be a linear transformation.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, proof-writing, linear-transformations

Let $V$ be an $n$-dimensional vector space, and let $T: V \rightarrow V$ be a linear transformation. Suppose that $W$ is a $T$-invariant subspace of $V$ having dimension $k$. Show that there is a basis $\beta$ for $V$ such that $[T]_{\beta}$ has the form $\begin{pmatrix} A & B \\ O & C \end{pmatrix}$, where $A$ is a $k \times k$-matrix and $O$ is the $(n-k) \times k$ zero matrix.

My sketch

Let $V$ be a vector space over $F$.

Choose a basis $\beta={v_1,v_2,...v_n}$ of V.

Choose a basis of subspace of W and extend to a basis of V,
{${w_1,...w_k,w_{k+1},...w_n}$}
Since w is T-invariant, $T(w) \subset w$,we have the existence of $a_{ij}$ for $1 \le i,j \le k$ such that $T(w_j)= \sum_{i=1}^k a_{ij}w_j$

Then I expanded $T(w_j)= \sum_{i=1}^k a_{ij}w_j$ and said the listed the transpose of $[T]_B$ to prove the point. Is it ok?

Comment: Why do you need $\beta$?

Comment: @amd to construct a basis for the whole vector space

Comment: You construct another basis right after that and never mention $\beta$ again. Of what use is it?

Comment: @amd yeah it seems pretty much no use in the proof, so you recommend deleting?